# Why is typescript optional class property set to undefined for es2022

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc, es2022

Typescript compiler handling of optional class properties seems to have changed from `es2021` to `es2022`.

```
class A {
    a?: string
    b?: string
    constructor() {
        this.b = 'asd'
    }
}
console.log(new A())
```

with tsconfig target=`es2021` results in

```
A: {
  "b": "asd"
}
```

with tsconfig target=`es2022` results in

```
A: {
  "a": undefined,
  "b": "asd"
}
```

I cannot find any documentation regarding this change. Is this really intended behaviour and why?

It is easy to reproduce in
[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&moduleResolution=99&module=1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XTAfgFzQgFwCcBLAOwHMU0AjbXQ0itaYAexPwIFdg8WCAKAJSJKTVHgAWRCADoq0ALzQA5JAAmy0dAC+SXa3YsQAUxkgWZfiWMB3OEMFIkQA)
by changing TS Config->Target

Comment: ES2021? Surely you mean ES3. In the playground it is currently set to *ES3*, and that produces `A` without an `a` field. Maybe you need to edit your question?

Comment: Yeah, the generated js code isn't the same in ES2022 & ES2021.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Uhhh what? It is the same for me. I only notice the "2021" behavior when targeting ES3...

Comment: @vera For me the change happens going from es2021 to es2022. es3 has same behavior as es2021.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is `useDefineForClassFields` :

> This flag is used as part of migrating to the upcoming standard
> version of class fields. TypeScript introduced class fields many years
> before it was ratified in TC39. The latest version of the upcoming
> specification has a different runtime behavior to TypeScript’s
> implementation but the same syntax.
>
> This flag switches to the upcoming ECMA runtime behavior.

[TS Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields)